# Add a timestamp to file name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

To avoid name collisions, I need to add a timestamp like extension to files my server creates.
I was thinking to something like yyyymmddhhss.
**What is the efficient way to generate a string like '201309091725'** (with eventually more digits) ?
`select  cast( sysdatetime() as varchar)` does include spaces, colons and dots, making that unusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select convert(varchar(30), getdate(),112) + 
       replace(convert(varchar(30), getdate(),108),':','')
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20374)**